# Why does SO use inline styles?

Tags: discussion

Why does SO use inline styles?
Here is a snippet,

```
<div id="footer-sites">
    <span style="color:#FE7A15;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#FE7A15;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://stackapps.com">api/apps</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#FE7A15;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://careers.stackoverflow.com">careers 2.0</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#E8272C;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://serverfault.com">serverfault.com</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#00AFEF;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://superuser.com">superuser.com</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#969696;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com">meta</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#46937D;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://area51.stackexchange.com">area&nbsp;51</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#C0D0DC;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://webapps.stackexchange.com">webapps</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#000000;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://gaming.stackexchange.com">gaming</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#dd4814;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://askubuntu.com">ubuntu</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#9ce4fe;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://webmasters.stackexchange.com">webmasters</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#cf4d3f;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://cooking.stackexchange.com">cooking</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#f4f28d;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://gamedev.stackexchange.com">game development</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#0f3559;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://math.stackexchange.com">math</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#f2f2f2;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://photo.stackexchange.com">photography</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#037187;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://stats.stackexchange.com">stats</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#f1e7cc;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://tex.stackexchange.com">tex</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#e1cdae;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://english.stackexchange.com">english</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#a2d9f6;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://cstheory.stackexchange.com">theoretical cs</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#1b3e6c;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://programmers.stackexchange.com">programmers</a>&nbsp; 
    <span style="color:#293a5d;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://unix.stackexchange.com">unix</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#bec0cb;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://apple.stackexchange.com">apple</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#939185;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://wordpress.stackexchange.com">wordpress</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#ebf5f5;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://physics.stackexchange.com">physics</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#4176ab;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://diy.stackexchange.com">home&nbsp;improvement</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#d1d8d7;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://gis.stackexchange.com">gis</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#e5e2d3;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://electronics.stackexchange.com">electrical&nbsp;engineering</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#a4c639;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://android.stackexchange.com">android</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#2e4e60;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://security.stackexchange.com">security</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#45bcb5;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://bicycles.stackexchange.com">bicycles</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#00adee;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://dba.stackexchange.com">dba</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#2edaf0;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://drupal.stackexchange.com">drupal</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#213951;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com">sharepoint</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#73abb3;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://scifi.stackexchange.com">scifi&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;fantasy</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#23629F;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://ux.stackexchange.com">user&nbsp;experience</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#faff72;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://skeptics.stackexchange.com">skeptics</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#623121;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://rpg.stackexchange.com">rpg</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#e4be88;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://judaism.stackexchange.com">judaism</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#ffecb1;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://mathematica.stackexchange.com">mathematica</a>&nbsp;
    <span style="color:#1b8598;font-size:140%">&#9632;</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://travel.stackexchange.com">travel</a>&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: Different sites have a different background color in their footer, so the color values in those styles probably have to be adjusted for each site.

Comment: Do you also ask the same question to Google, Facebook, Youtube, etc..?

Comment: @Chichiray: If they provide me a platform like SO to ask questions about them. I certainly would.

Comment: @BilltheLizard You have a good point but I don't *think* that's the case, go to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ and look at the "gaming" square in the footer (it's invisible). As far as I can tell they're all the same.

Comment: @Fahad, why do you care? To answer your question though, I presume their CMS generates them automatically for convenience. I doubt very much a human ever generated the HTML.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Very good point made.

Comment: @FacebookAnswers: Because inline styles are not the standard and gives errors:http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=www.stackoverflow.com&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Answer (score 7):

Why is there so much whitespace in the HTML source? Why do they use tables for layout?

But seriously, sometimes it makes sense if talking about **total** bytes sent to the browser (I feel like this should be a Stack Overflow answer). If we're just talking about the inline color, it's more bytes to put it in a stylesheet, even with a one-letter class name, since the styles aren't reused.

Let's say we're just talking about the color:

```
<span style="color:#FE7A15">&#9632;</span>
```

VS

```
<span class="x">&#9632;</span>.x{color:#FE7A15}
```

The second one's a bit longer, even with the stupidly short class name, and it has to be repeated in the stylesheet for each square. Adding sensible class names to each square and moving the colors to a stylesheet would absolutely make the source HTML/CSS larger.

The thing that would make sense is maybe moving the inline font size:

```
<span class="footer-square" style="color:#FE7A15">&#9632;</span>

.footer-square{font-size:140%}
```

Actually now that I look at it, it would still make the source code bigger, so nevermind.

In any case, I don't think it's a big deal. The real answer is probably just something like "who cares, it's easier this way", but for sake of argument let's say "it's faster".

Comment: I was just curious because I read some great arguments on not to use inline styles and W3C does not recommend them. Thanks for the answers. Clears out the reason very well.

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where it might make sense, as the styles will not be reusable (they *could* be, but aren't). It always depends, but yeah generally you want to avoid inline styles and javascript.

Comment: Pragmatism wins out over purity every time.